# Trigger UIApplicationWillTerminateNotification for "stop" Xcode action

Tags: ios, xcode, uiapplicationdelegate

I noticed that `UIApplicationWillTerminateNotification` is not getting sent if I stop the executable from Xcode. Is there a clean way to get it to call?

Answer (score 0):

Use this code below. It will work great!

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(applicationWillTerminate:) name:UIApplicationWillTerminateNotification object:nil];
```